# Plot exponential curves

Tags: limits, asymptotics, exponential-function, graphing-functions, curves

I'm writing here because it's more like a math question than $\LaTeX$.
I would need to draw some curves like this:

[exponential curves](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIgKN.jpg)

these are curves drawn at different values of a constant parameter $r$. The equation of these curves is

$$ \xi = \dfrac{A_\mathrm{d} \times \exp\left\{-\dfrac{E_\mathrm{A,d}}{RT}\right\} - r  } 
{A_\mathrm{d} \times \exp\left\{-\dfrac{E_\mathrm{A,d}}{RT}\right\} + A_\mathrm{i} \times \exp\left\{-\dfrac{E_\mathrm{A,i}}{RT}\right\}}$$

Where $A_\mathrm{d}, E_\mathrm{A,d}, A_\mathrm{d}, E_\mathrm{A,i}$ and $R$ are constants, with
$E_\mathrm{A,d} < E_\mathrm{A,i}$

the independent variable is $T$.
These curves were plotted for values of $r$ increasing from the top down. $\xi$ is between 0 and 1, $T$ is between 0 and $\infty$. The asymptotes of any curve for $T$ approches to $\infty$ is

$$ \dfrac{A_\mathrm{d}-r}{A_\mathrm{d}+A_\mathrm{i}} $$

Could you suggest a simplified form of this equation that returns the same curves, so I can use it on pgfplots?

Comment: You’re a chemist I believe?

Comment: Yes I am! xi is the reaction extent, T is the absolute temperature. E_a is the activation energy, A the pre-exponential factor

Comment: What are typical values of $ E_{A,d} , E_{A, i} $ and $R$ ?

Comment: @WhyHosamWhy typical values of $E_\mathrm{A}$ is $10^5 J \times mol^{-1}$, and $R = 8.31 \; J \times K^{-1} \times mol^{-1}$.

Comment: In your first equation you have $-r$ but in the second asymptotic expression you have $+r$. Is that a typo?

Comment: Yes, is a typo!

Comment: Corrected in the second asymptotic expression